# Unable to display image on JPanel

Tags: java, image, swing, jdbc

Here is My Code Snippet:

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from patrika where jantacode = ?");
                    ps.setString(1, jComboBox1.getItemAt(jComboBox1.getSelectedIndex()));
                    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
                    rs.next();
                    jTextField2.setText(rs.getString("companycode"));
                    jTextField3.setText(rs.getString("manufacturer"));
                    jTextField4.setText(rs.getString("purchaseprice"));
                    jTextField5.setText(rs.getString("wholesaleprice"));
                    jTextField6.setText(rs.getString("retailprice"));
                    jTextField7.setText(rs.getString("location"));
                    jTextField1.setText(rs.getString("stock"));

                    //Getting and displaying image
                    Blob blob = rs.getBlob("image");
                    int blobLength = (int) blob.length();  
                    byte[] bytes = blob.getBytes(1, blobLength);
                    blob.free();
                    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
                    Graphics2D g = img.createGraphics();
                    jPanel1.paint(g);
                    jPanel1.repaint();
```

Everything works fine but the jPanel does not get the image drawn on it.

The Snapshot of the same is also attached. can anyone please help me finding out my mistake please?

[image: Problem Screenshot]

Comment: Use a `JLabel` to display the image. BTW - the above code is painting the panel to the image, not the image to the panel.

Comment: And as mentioned by @mKorbel, review the document on the [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to paint an image to a JPanel, you have to override its paintComponent() method as you want to paint it every frame.

It would look something like this, from the docs:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    // Let UI Delegate paint first, which 
    // includes background filling since 
    // this component is opaque.

    super.paintComponent(g);       
    g.drawString("This is my custom Panel!",10,20);
    redSquare.paintSquare(g);
}
```

Now you load the image and only once paint it to the panel.

Spend some more time with the docs :)
This would do great: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html

Comment: to read Oracle tutorial `2D Graphics`, part `Working with Images`, there isn't something about `JPanel` with `paint()`, but by override `paintComponent`, and with `super.paintComponent` as 1st code line inside:-)

Comment: answer goes good way, but methods, commands into  sentences are wrong

Comment: @mKorbel Thanks for the fix, did not remember the correct method name from the top of my head :)

Comment: The easiest way is to just use a JLabel and add an ImageIcon to the label.